# How would I make a random word generator in python for a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to make a quiz but I want to know how to make a random word generator.

The 4 words I need to be in this generator are: add, minus, divide and times.

```
question = random.randint(1,4)
if (question==1):
elif (question==2):
elif (question==3):
elif (question==4):
```

I'm using this for now but I would prefer for it to be words

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice). Using it, you don't need to index.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(['add', 'minus', 'divide', 'times'])
'add'
>>> random.choice(['add', 'minus', 'divide', 'times'])
'times'
```

Comment: That should work. You could also make that a variable. Ex:
choice = random.choice(['add', 'minus', 'divide', 'times'])
then do
print(choice)